# Swiper.js is not looping properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to have a slider over various projects. However, even though the content is able to be scrolled the contents are not looping properly. Please help me out. I am a beginner and I am working on my portfolio website. I downloaded packages from swiper.js but when I use it, it works fine but it does not loop back from the beginning after ending the loop.

```js
let swiperPortfolio = new Swiper('.portfolio__container', {
  cssMode: true,
  loop: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  autoplay: {
    delay: 5000,
  },
  mousewheel: true,
  autoplay: true,
  keyboard: true,
});
```

```css
.portfolio__container {
  overflow: initial;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.portfolio__content {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.portfolio__img {
  width: 256px;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  justify-self: center;
}

.portfolio__title {
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-0-5);
}

.portfolio__description {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-0-75);
}

.portfolio__button:hover .button__icon {
  transform: translateX(0.25rem);
}

.swiper-button-prev::after,
.swiper-button-next::after {
  content: '';
}

.swiper-portfolio-icon {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  left: -4rem;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  right: -4rem;
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets {
  bottom: -8.5rem;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<section class="secondSection" id="portfolio">
  <span class="textgray">Some projects I worked on</span>
  <h1>Projects</h1>
  <div class="portfolio__container container swiper-container">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="portfolio__content grid swiper-slide">
        <img src="assets/img/portfolio1.jpg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">

        <div class="portfolio__data">
          <h3 class="portfolio__title">Custom Keyword Spotting</h3>
          <p class="portfolio__description">Detecting Custom wakewords from a given speech <br>data</p>
          <a href="#" class="button--flex button--small portfolio__button">
            Demo
            <i class="uil uil-arrow-right button__icon"></i>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="portfolio__content grid swiper-slide">
        <img src="assets/img/portfolio2.jpg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
        <div class="portfolio__data">
          <h3 class="portfolio__title">Classroom Activity Recognition</h3>
          <p class="portfolio__description">Predicting the activity of classroom with respective <br>SPL levels in the speech signal</p>
          <a href="#" class="button--flex button--small portfolio__button">
            Demo
            <i class="uil uil-arrow-right button__icon"></i>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="portfolio__content grid swiper-slide">
        <img src="assets/img/portfolio3.jpg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
        <div class="portfolio__data">
          <h3 class="portfolio__title">Contactless Auth System</h3>
          <p class="portfolio__description">A contactless system to monitor the entry and <br>exit points</p>
          <a href="#" class="button--flex button--small portfolio__button">
            Demo
            <i class="uil uil-arrow-right button__icon"></i>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next">
      <i class="uil uil-angle-right-b swiper-portfolio-icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev">
      <i class="uil uil-angle-left-b swiper-portfolio-icon"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the documentation [#param-cssMode](https://swiperjs.com/swiper-api#param-cssMode):

> When enabled it will use modern CSS Scroll Snap API. It doesn't support all of Swiper's features

```js
let swiperPortfolio = new Swiper('.portfolio__container', {
  // cssMode: true,
  loop: true,
  navigation: {
    nextEl: '.swiper-button-next',
    prevEl: '.swiper-button-prev',
  },
  pagination: {
    el: '.swiper-pagination',
    clickable: true,
  },
  autoplay: {
    delay: 5000,
  },
  mousewheel: true,
  autoplay: true,
  keyboard: true,
});
```

```css
.portfolio__container {
  overflow: initial;
  overflow-wrap: break-word;
}

.portfolio__content {
  padding: 0 1.5rem;
  display: flex;
  margin-top: 80px;
}

.portfolio__img {
  width: 256px;
  border-radius: 5rem;
  justify-self: center;
}

.portfolio__title {
  font-size: var(--h3-font-size);
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-0-5);
}

.portfolio__description {
  margin-bottom: var(--mb-0-75);
}

.portfolio__button:hover .button__icon {
  transform: translateX(0.25rem);
}

.swiper-button-prev::after,
.swiper-button-next::after {
  content: '';
}

.swiper-portfolio-icon {
  font-size: 2rem;
  color: var(--first-color);
}

.swiper-button-prev {
  left: -4rem;
}

.swiper-button-next {
  right: -4rem;
}

.swiper-container-horizontal>.swiper-pagination-bullets {
  bottom: -8.5rem;
}

.swiper-pagination-bullet-active {
  background-color: var(--first-color);
}

.swiper-button-prev,
.swiper-button-next,
.swiper-pagination-bullet {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/swiper@10/swiper-bundle.min.css">
<section class="secondSection" id="portfolio">
  <span class="textgray">Some projects I worked on</span>
  <h1>Projects</h1>
  <div class="portfolio__container container swiper">
    <div class="swiper-wrapper">
      <div class="portfolio__content grid swiper-slide">
        <img src="assets/img/portfolio1.jpg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">

        <div class="portfolio__data">
          <h3 class="portfolio__title">Custom Keyword Spotting</h3>
          <p class="portfolio__description">Detecting Custom wakewords from a given speech <br>data</p>
          <a href="#" class="button--flex button--small portfolio__button">
            Demo
            <i class="uil uil-arrow-right button__icon"></i>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="portfolio__content grid swiper-slide">
        <img src="assets/img/portfolio2.jpg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
        <div class="portfolio__data">
          <h3 class="portfolio__title">Classroom Activity Recognition</h3>
          <p class="portfolio__description">Predicting the activity of classroom with respective <br>SPL levels in the speech signal</p>
          <a href="#" class="button--flex button--small portfolio__button">
            Demo
            <i class="uil uil-arrow-right button__icon"></i>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>

      <div class="portfolio__content grid swiper-slide">
        <img src="assets/img/portfolio3.jpg" alt="" class="portfolio__img">
        <div class="portfolio__data">
          <h3 class="portfolio__title">Contactless Auth System</h3>
          <p class="portfolio__description">A contactless system to monitor the entry and <br>exit points</p>
          <a href="#" class="button--flex button--small portfolio__button">
            Demo
            <i class="uil uil-arrow-right button__icon"></i>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-next">
      <i class="uil uil-angle-right-b swiper-portfolio-icon"></i>
    </div>
    <div class="swiper-button-prev">
      <i class="uil uil-angle-left-b swiper-portfolio-icon"></i>
    </div>

    <div class="swiper-pagination"></div>
  </div>

</section>
```

Comment: I did look into the same and the number of slides are correct

Comment: Yes, you're right, it's not about the number of slides. I looked at your code more carefully and found the reason is the use of `cssMode`. I updated my answer.